# Section added by \addcontentsline on the wrong page

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, page-numbering

I am adding a section with the bibliography references by using `\addcontentsline` in order to add a link to the table of contents. Unfortunately the link in the table of contents links to a wrong page, previous to the page with the bibliography.

How can I immediately place an anchor for a new section in table of contents?

```
\printbibliography[heading=offline,filter=offline]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\printbibliography[heading=online,filter=online]
```

Comment: How do you define the `online` heading?

Comment: It's also important to know the document class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `\printbibliography` command indicates that you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). To add bibliographies to the ToC with `biblatex` (without numbering them), normally one should add the `heading=bibintoc` option to `\printbibliography`. See section 3.6.7 of the `biblatex` manual for details.

As you seem to have defined a custom `online` heading, you may have to change its definition so that it resembles that of `bibintoc` (which is tailored to the document class and may be found in `biblatex.def`).

Answer (score 27):

The following comments can be used more in general.

### The main minimal example

The following example is the basis of the next steps.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibfilter{online}{ type=online }
\defbibfilter{offline}{ not type=online }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{foo}
\cite{companion} \& \cite{ctan}

\noindent\hrulefill

\printbibliography[filter=offline]

\noindent\hrulefill

\printbibliography[filter=online]

\end{document}
```

The next image shows the result.

[image]

We mention that the heading of the bibliographies are equal and not shown in the table of contents (toc).

## Suppose you are using a standard class

### First approach -- working with `biblatex` options

The first approach based on the idea that we only use the option provided by the package `biblatex` for the command `\printbibliograpy`.

First of all we want a special name for your heading. This can be done be the option `title`. So we simple set:

```
\printbibliography[filter=offline,title=Offline,]

\printbibliography[filter=online,title=Online,]
```

With this modification we doesn't have an entry in the toc. To provide an entry in the toc we can use the option `heading`. `biblatex`offers different values for this option. Here a small range:

- `bibliography`:

  - unnumbered -- no entry in toc -- chapter level (section for articles)
- `subbibliography`:

  - unnumbered -- no entry in toc -- section level (subsection for articles)
- `bibintoc`:

  - unnumbered -- entry in toc -- chapter level (section for articles)
- `subbibintoc`:

  - unnumbered -- entry in toc -- section level (subsection for articles)
- `bibnumbered`:

  - numbered -- entry in toc -- chapter level (section for articles)
- `subbibnumbered`:

  - numbered -- entry in toc -- section level (subsection for articles)

Based on this information we can expand your examples as follows:

```
\printbibliography[filter=offline,title=Offline,heading=subbibintoc]

\printbibliography[filter=online,title=Online,subbibintoc]
```

The example demonstrate the first apprach:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibfilter{online}{ type=online }
\defbibfilter{offline}{ not type=online }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{foo}
\cite{companion} \& \cite{ctan}

\noindent\hrulefill
\section{References}

\printbibliography[filter=online,title=Offline,heading=subbibintoc]

\noindent\hrulefill

\printbibliography[filter=online,title=Online,heading=subbibintoc]


\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second approach - define your own header

In normal cases the standard option should be enough. However you can define your own special heading with the command `\defbibheading`.  The standard syntax is

```
\defbibheading{⟨name⟩}[⟨title⟩]{⟨code⟩}
```

The defined heading can be used by the optional argument `heading` (see above).

We take an example. The heading should be unnumbered but with an entry in the toc:

```
\defbibheading{myheading}[\bibname]{%
 \begin{center}
  \hrulefill#1\markboth{#1}{#1}\hrulefill%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
 \end{center}%
}
```

Based on these heading in combination with the option `title` we can create the following example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibfilter{online}{ type=online }
\defbibfilter{offline}{ not type=online }
\defbibheading{myheading}[\bibname]{%
 \begin{center}
  \hrulefill#1\markboth{#1}{#1}\hrulefill%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
 \end{center}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{foo}
\cite{companion} \& \cite{ctan}

\noindent\hrulefill
\section{References}

\printbibliography[filter=offline,title=Offline,heading=myheading]

\printbibliography[filter=online,title=Online,heading=myheading]


\end{document}
```

[image]

## Suppose you are using a KOMA class

`KOMA` provides additional document class options to manipulate the heading of a bibliography. The benefit of this method you can set the option global. All options provided by `KOMA` are compatible with `biblatex`. The key of the document class is `bibliography`. A range of possibilities are listed below. Of course all listed  approaches in the above section can be used in combination with `KOMA`.

- `notoc`:

  - unnumbered -- no entry in toc -- chapter level (section for articles)
- `totoc`:

  - unnumbered -- entry in toc -- chapter level (section for articles)
- `totocnumbered`:

  - numbered -- entry in toc -- chapter level (section for articles)

Based of your main MWE here the modification:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibfilter{online}{ type=online }
\defbibfilter{offline}{ not type=online }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{foo}
\cite{companion} \& \cite{ctan}

\noindent\hrulefill

\printbibliography[filter=offline,title=Offline]

\printbibliography[filter=online,title=Online]


\end{document}
```

[image]

## Suppose you are using memoir

This is really simple. `memoir` creates an entry in the toc as default.

Comment: This is a great answer and should be the accepted one! Also, +1 for the KOMA class section! Helped me a lot!