# tocbibind does not add an numbered entry to the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Section added by \addcontentsline on the wrong page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/section-added-by-addcontentsline-on-the-wrong-page)

I have a document in report class with

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  
\linespread{1.5}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=numeric,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,maxcitenames=2{biblatex}  
\bibliography{mybib}  
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}  
\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents  
\chapter{test}  
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

This does not add an entry for the bibliography. Changing `\printbibliography` to

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

works, although I have no idea what it actually does. Still, the entry is not numbered, it looks like this

```
Table of Contents  
Table of Contents ................ 1  
1 test ........................... 2  
Literatur ........................ 3
```

My questions: What does `heading=bibintoc` and how can I have the bibliography numbered automatically?

Comment: Welcome! See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/section-added-by-addcontentsline-on-the-wrong-page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `tocbibind`, you can simply use the `bibnumbered` heading which will create a numbered heading which is also added to the table of contents:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
```

Comment: Could you extend your answer for displaying the list of figures and list of tables in the ToC without the tocbibind package? Thank you!