# Prevent biblatex from printing a header

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

When using `biblatex` together with `myheadings`, `biblatex` adds a header `REFERENCES` on the pages where the bibliography is. How do I prevent that?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings} % page numbers in top right corner
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra} % XeLaTeX
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % support TeX conventions like ``--''
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = authoryear, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location = local]{test.bib}

\begin{document}

I want to cite \cite{brunner1965}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My .bib file:

```
@PREAMBLE{
    "\newcommand{\aumlaut}{\char"00E4}" #
    "\newcommand{\uumlaut}{\char"00FC}"
        }

@BOOK{brunner1965,
    AUTHOR = "Karl Brunner",
    TITLE = "Altenglische {G}rammatik",
    YEAR = "1965",
    ADDENDUM = "{N}ach der angels{\aumlaut}chsischen {G}rammatik von {E}duard {S}ievers",
    EDITION = "Dritte, neubearbeitete {A}uflage",
    LANGUAGE = "German",
    LOCATION = "T{\uumlaut}bingen",
    NUMBER = "3",
    PAGETOTAL = "x + 436",
    PUBLISHER = "Max Niemeyer",
    SERIES = "{S}ammlung kurzer {G}rammatiken germanischer {D}ialekte. {A}. {H}auptreihe"}
```

Comment: Which document class do you use? The typesetting of headers is governed mainly by the design decisions embedded in a document class (and, relatedly, the page style associated with a document class). For instance, in the `article` document class, `biblatex` will *not*, by default, typeset headers.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/section-added-by-addcontentsline-on-the-wrong-page/52829#52829

Comment: @Mico: I do use the ``article`` class:
``\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, onecolumn, oneside, notitlepage]{article}``

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I didn't understand. There's a guide for how to add your own header, but what should I do to have _no_ header?

Comment: you can define your own header with `section*`. The link is only an inspiration to find the correct section inside the documentation.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: How do I use `section*` to prevent `biblatex` from adding the header? I have found the relevant sections in the documentation, but I don't understand what I need to do.

Comment: Use `\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\section*{#1}}`

Comment: @Sverre Please add a _complete_ example. As Mico says `biblatex` won't typeset headers by default.

Comment: @Thorsten: That's wrong. `biblatex` uses `\markboth`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I guess he's talking about headers and _not_ headings.

Comment: @Thorsten: Sorry. I edit my comment. I know it isn't well formulated

Comment: I found it it's due to how ``myheadings`` and ``biblatex`` interact. I've made a minimally working example which illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the following remarks I guess you are printing some headings by setting `\pagestyle` (maybe a package).

The package `biblatex` defines some special headings which can be called by the option `heading`. The default setting for the article class is:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

The command `\markboth` procure that you get a heading. The simplest way is the redefinition by

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\section*{#1}}
```

without the command `\markboth`.