# Bibliography not in ToC when using biblatex/biber

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, naming

I just managed to switch from using BibTeX to `biblatex` with the biber backend. My references now appear how I want. However I have two new issues.

1) How do I change "Bibliography" to references? The old `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}` does nothing.

2) How do I make the Bibliography appear in my Table of Contents because it now doesn't when using `\printbibliography` as per `biblatex`. Is it just a case of doing the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}`? Or is there a more subtle method?

Comment: There is an easy answer (see `\defbibheading` in the `biblatex` manual), but it depends on what sectional level your bibliography heading needs to be.  Is it the equivalent of a chapter or section (or something else).

Comment: @jon Actually there are some predefined headings that use the correct (for the respective class) sectioning unit.

Comment: @lockstep -- Indeed, but wouldn't you need to use `references` instead of `bibliography` in your `\DefineBibliographyStrings` if the class used was `article` (or the `article` option was used in `memoir`)?  My comment was meant mainly to bring out whether the looked-for answer was expecting to put the bibliography entry at a specific level in the ToC (e.g., sometimes books have the bibliography listed as a 'sectional' division rather than as equivalent to a chapter).

Comment: @jon That's correct -- I was assuming that the OP, as he talked about his redefinition of `\bibname` not working, was using a class that features `\bibname` (and not `\refname`).

Comment: @lockstep -- Ah, point taken.  I guess he is looking for a 'chapter'-level entry as well.  (I was thinking about the answer too generally....)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Section added by \addcontentsline on the wrong page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/section-added-by-addcontentsline-on-the-wrong-page)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel You're indeed right with regard to question 2, but not with regard to no. 1. (Which, OTOH, shows the wisdom of the one-question-at-a-time rule.)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

See sections 3.6.7, 3.8, and 4.9.2.1 of the `biblatex` manual. In the following example, I'm assuming that you a) use a class that features `\bibname` (i.e., one with the `\chapter` sectioning command) b) don't want to number your bibliography chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will give this a whirl chaps! Looks like it will solve my problem! Thanks very much!

Comment: For those who just want to include the bibliography in the ToC, the critical line here is `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`.

Comment: I'm trying the opposite ``\printbibliography[heading=nobibintoc]``, but getting an error, can't find info on this...

Answer (score 53):

Though the problem is solved, here is my alternative solution for `biblatex`.

`\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]`.

The `title` would override the section title.

Based on lockstep's codes, My solution would be

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I also want a number (or capital letter) in front of "References"? I mean it continues the numbering. Here "2  References".

Comment: @skan. replace the "heading=bibintoc" with "heading=bibnumbered" in "printbibliography" command should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (if you use the `\printbibheading` command in order to title your bibliography section) is: `\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]`

Edit:

Here is the case, if you want to divide your bibliography in groups, and put also a heading
`\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc] \printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Books}] \printbibliography[type=article,heading=subbibliography,title={Articles}]`