# BibLaTeX: bibliography not appearing in table of contents

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

I have a report created in Latex:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
For more information see \cite{ahu61}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Bibliography is not present in the Table Of Contents. How to fix?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`. But are you using bibtex as you state in the title and the tag, or biblatex as it appears in the MWE?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, Your solution works. I compile  the `.aux` file with `bibtex`. I use the `[]` in  \usepackage[]{biblatex}` to specify how bibliography should be sorted and cited.

Comment: Ooh, I'm sorry. I didn't see the `backend=bibtex` there. You are correct. If it worked, then your question is a duplicate of: [Bibliography not in ToC when using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67153/134574).