# Structuring the bibliography by headings and subheadings

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

In my Bibliography, I need two categories: Primary Sources and Secondary Sources. The first needs to be subdivided into Manuscripts and Published Works.

So, I thought I could use the following code:

```
\printbibheading
    \printbibliography[keyword={Manuscripts}, heading=subbibliography, title={Manuscripts}]
    \printbibliography[keyword={Primary Source}, heading=subbibliography, title={Primary Sources}]
    \printbibliography[keyword={Secondary Source}, heading=subbibliography, title={Secondary Sources}]
```

This, however, gives me three categories, but I would like to have only two with the first being subdivided. In other words I need something like this:

```
\printbibliography[keyword={Manuscripts},
    heading=subbibliography,
    title={Primary Sources},
    subtitle={Manuscripts}]  %% subtitle={...}
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/section-added-by-addcontentsline-on-the-wrong-page/52829#52829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, I could use something like this:

```
\printbibheading
    \section*{Primary Sources}
        \subsection*{Manuscripts}
    \printbibliography[keyword={Manuscripts}, heading=none]
        \subsection*{Published Works}
    \printbibliography[keyword={Primary Source}, heading=none]
    \section*{Secondary Sources}
    \printbibliography[keyword={Secondary Source}, heading=none]
```

Maybe, however, there are other, i.e., more elegant, solutions possible.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you could do the following to put both sectioning commands in one `\defbibheading`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibheading{multilevel}{% 
  \section*{Primary Sources}
  \subsection*{Manuscripts}}

\begin{document}                                                             
\nocite{knuth:ct}
\printbibliography[heading=multilevel]
\end{document}
```

A fuller example would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibheading{multilevel}{%
  \section*{Primary Sources}
  \subsection*{Manuscripts}}

\defbibheading{published}{%
  \subsection*{Published Works}}

\defbibheading{secondary}{%
  \section*{Secondary Sources}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{mss}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{pri}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{sec}

\addtocategory{mss}{knurth:ct}
\addtocategory{pri}{knuth:ct:a}
\addtocategory{sec}{knuth:ct:b}

\begin{document}

\nocite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography[heading=multilevel, notcategory={pri}, notcategory={sec}]
% \printbibliography[heading=multilevel, category={mss}]
\printbibliography[heading=published,  category={pri}]
\printbibliography[heading=secondary,  category={sec}]

\end{document}
```

But for some reason it does not work correctly if you use three bibliography categories, though it will work if you use `notcategory`....  However, it does work fine with three different `keyword`s (e.g., `keyword={mss}`, `keyword={pri}`, `keyword={sec}`) as long as your `.bib` file entries have the appropriate `keywords` field. (Unfortunately, the `biblatex-examples.bib` that ships with `biblatex` only has two categories of `keywords`: primary  and secondary.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Necro'ing after four years because I had a similar problem and found a better solution. Biblatex 3.5 allows to improve the solution a tad. From the manual:

> \defbibheading{*name*}[*title*]{*code*}
>
> This command defines
> bibliography headings. The *name* is an identifier to be passed to the
> heading option of \printbibliography or \printbibheading and
> \printbiblist when selecting the heading. The *code* should be LaTeX
> code generating a fully-fledged heading, including page headers and an
> entry in the table of contents, if desired. If \printbibliography or
> \printbiblist are invoked with a title option, the title will be
> passed to the heading definition as #1. If not, the default title
> specified by the optional *title* argument is passed as #1 instead.
> The *title* argument will typically be \bibname, \refname, or
> \biblistname (see § 4.9.2.1).

OK, that is not very clear, but what it means is that you can write a macro to produce the bibliographic heading. In the above case, one could do something like:

```
\defbibheading{firstlevel}[]{%
    \section*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}

\defbibheading{secondlevel}[]{%
    \subsection*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}
(...)
    \section*{Primary Sources}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Primary Sources}
    \printbibliography[keyword=published, heading=secondlevel, title={Published Works}]
    \printbibliography[keyword=manuscripts, heading=secondlevel, title={Manuscripts}]

    \printbibliography[keyword=secondary, heading=firstlevel, title = {Secondary Sources}]
```

You still need an explicit call to create the second section; maybe a LateX-guru could refine the code definitions to avoid this. But I would argue this solution is cleaner.