# Making bibliography appear in ToC (BibLaTeX, Article class)

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex

I'm having trouble getting my bibliography visible in my Table of Contents. I've googled and read especially [the earlier thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/making-the-bibliography-appear-in-the-table-of-contents/144517#144517), but still can't get this to work.

See below part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

However, I still can't get the References to ToC.

Would anyone have any further tips?

Comment: Have you tried adding something like \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References} to the main body of your document (just were your bibliography is)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/section-added-by-addcontentsline-on-the-wrong-page/52829#52829

Comment: A hint: `biblatex` uses `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography`. One big difference is that `\bibliography` needs the filename without extension.