# Tried to change Bibliography header style, now \printbibliography produces no output

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, biblatex-chicago

So I've been trying to change the References section style to match the subsection ones (instead of the section), and I've tried pretty much all the suggestions I could find here and on Google.

I've found some codes that produce my **visual** expected output:

[image]

But that also makes it so that the `\printbibliography` produces no output.

Can someone please enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?

For what it's worth, I'm working fully on Overleaf, and the logs show no errors.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authordate,natbib=true,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc,doi=false,url=true,isbn=false,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@techreport{ipea2022,
    author = {Góes, G. and Firmino, A. and Martins, F.},
    title ={{Painel da Gig Economy no setor de transportes do Brasil: quem, onde, quantos e quanto ganham}},
    institution = {IPEA},
    number = {55},
    year = {2022},
    type = {Nota de conjuntura},
}

@techreport{fiocruz2022,
    author = {Carvalho, C. C. and Viacava, F. and Oliveira, R. D. and Martins, M. and Abrahão, L. D.},
    title = {{Internações por Condições Sensíveis à Atenção Primária (ICSAP): análise do quesito raça/cor}},
    institution = {{PROADESS}},
    number = {10},
    year ={2022},
    type = {Boletim Informativo}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}


\addto{\captionsbrazil}{%
  \renewcommand{\printbibliography}{\subsection*{\refname}}
  }

% Columns
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}

% Define color
\definecolor{IEPS-A}{RGB}{255,194,14}
\definecolor{IEPS-L}{RGB}{247,148,29}

% Section heading styles
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{IEPS-A!30}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\thesection\ #1}}}

%\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\color{IEPS-A}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\color{IEPS-L}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\color{IEPS-A}}

% Section heading spacing (reduced space below headings)
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{3ex plus 7.2ex minus .2ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1.2ex minus .2ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1.2ex minus .2ex}{0ex}

% Define a title note command
\newcommand\titlenote[1]{\renewcommand\@titlenote{#1}}


\begin{document}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Title}}
\author[1]{}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\par

\section{Introduction}
\medskip

\lipsum[1-1]  \citep{ipea2022} \citep{fiocruz2022}.

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection*{Authors}
\medskip

\textbf{Author 1}\\
\textit{\footnotesize{Affiliation}}\\

\subsection*{Thanks}
\smallskip

So long, and thanks for all the fish!

\printbibliography

\end{multicols}

\vspace{1 cm}

\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt}

\vspace{1 cm}

\begin{center}
www.website.com
\end{center}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: The `\renewcommand{\printbibliography}{\subsection*{\refname}}` in `\addto{\captionsbrazil}` essentially redefines the command that is supposed to print the bibliography to just issue a subsection heading and nothing else. In particular no bibliography is produced. Where did you find this piece of code (or who suggested it was the way to go)? Bibliography headings can be customised with the `heading` option to `\printbibliography` and if that is not enough there is `\defbibheading`. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41818/35864.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You need to write `heading=subbibliography` as option for `\printbibliography` which produces bibliography as subsection

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authordate,natbib=true,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc,doi=false,url=true,isbn=false,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
    @techreport{ipea2022,
        author = {Góes, G. and Firmino, A. and Martins, F.},
        title ={{Painel da Gig Economy no setor de transportes do Brasil: quem, onde, quantos e quanto ganham}},
        institution = {IPEA},
        number = {55},
        year = {2022},
        type = {Nota de conjuntura},
    }
    
    @techreport{fiocruz2022,
        author = {Carvalho, C. C. and Viacava, F. and Oliveira, R. D. and Martins, M. and Abrahão, L. D.},
        title = {{Internações por Condições Sensíveis à Atenção Primária (ICSAP): análise do quesito raça/cor}},
        institution = {{PROADESS}},
        number = {10},
        year ={2022},
        type = {Boletim Informativo}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}


% Columns
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}

% Define color
\definecolor{IEPS-A}{RGB}{255,194,14}
\definecolor{IEPS-L}{RGB}{247,148,29}

% Section heading styles
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
{}
{0pt}
{\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{IEPS-A!30}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\thesection\ #1}}}

%\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\color{IEPS-A}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\color{IEPS-L}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\color{IEPS-A}}

% Section heading spacing (reduced space below headings)
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{3ex plus 7.2ex minus .2ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1.2ex minus .2ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1.2ex minus .2ex}{0ex}

% Define a title note command
\newcommand\titlenote[1]{\renewcommand\@titlenote{#1}}


\begin{document}
    
    \title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Title}}
    \author[1]{}
    
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \par
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \medskip
    
    \lipsum[1-1]  \citep{ipea2022} \citep{fiocruz2022}.
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        
        \subsection*{Authors}
        \medskip
        
        \textbf{Author 1}\\
        \textit{\footnotesize{Affiliation}}\\
        
        \subsection*{Thanks}
        \smallskip
        
        So long, and thanks for all the fish!
        
        \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
        
    \end{multicols}
    
    \vspace{1 cm}
    
    \noindent \rule{\linewidth}{0.25pt}
    
    \vspace{1 cm}
    
    \begin{center}
        www.website.com
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!! Can't believe it was something so simple!